# Why does the following code result in infinite recursion?

Tags: swift

```
class TestClass : NSObject {

    var definitions: NSSet = NSSet()

    func addDefinitionsObject(value: AnyObject) {
        self.mutableSetValueForKey("definitions").addObject(value)
    }

    func removeDefinitionsObject(value: AnyObject) {
        // this method is never called
        self.mutableSetValueForKey("definitions").removeObject(value)
    }
}

var test = TestClass()
test.addDefinitionsObject("yo")
```

Running this causes infinite recursion, which ultimately crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Any ideas why this is happening?

What's weird is that this only happens if `removeDefinitionsObject` is defined. If I remove that function, the issue goes away.

Comment: Wow, generated list mutators? Changing the name of addDefinitionsObject to something else also solves the issue, this looks really weird.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ["Accessor Search Pattern for Unordered Collections"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#/) in the "Key-Value Coding Programming Guide"
(emphasis mine):

> The default search pattern for `mutableSetValueForKey:` is as follows:
>
> - Searches the receiver's class for methods whose names match the
>     patterns `add<Key>Object:` and `remove<Key>Object:` (corresponding to the
>     `NSMutableSet` primitive methods `addObject:` and `removeObject:`
>     respectively) and also `add<Key>:` and `remove<Key>:` (corresponding to
>     NSMutableSet methods unionSet: and minusSet:).
>     **If at least one addition method and at least one removal method** are found each
>     `NSMutableSet` message sent to the collection proxy object will result
>     in some combination of `add<Key>Object:`, `remove<Key>Object:`, `add<Key>:`,
>     and `remove<Key>:` messages being sent to the original receiver of
>     `mutableSetValueForKey:`.
> - ...

Which means that if both `addDefinitionsObject` and `removeDefinitionsObject`
are implemented in your class, then

```
self.mutableSetValueForKey("definitions").addObject(value)
```

calls

```
self.addDefinitionsObject(value)
```

hence the recursion.